# How to find out how many numbers in my vector is lower than a given number

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I want to find out how many numbers in my vector are lower than a given value. I came up with this code but get the following warning message. I've tried different things like comparing vectors of the same size etc. but nothing seems to work.

```
test.seq <- seq(from = 20000, to = 0, length.out = 100) 
n.lower <- matrix(0, nrow = 1, ncol = 1)
for(i in 1:100){
   if(test.seq < 10000){
      n.lower <- n.lower + 1
   }
}

Warning message:
In if (test.seq < 1000) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to do it:

```
sum(test.seq < 10000)
[1] 50
```

If you want to use a loop:

```
n.lower <- 0

for(i in 1:100){
  if(test.seq[i] < 10000){
    n.lower <- n.lower + 1
  }
}

n.lower
[1] 50
```

-- data

```
test.seq <- seq(from = 20000, to = 0, length.out = 100)
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `length` and `which`

```
length(which(test.seq < 10000))
[1] 50
```

---

or the `for` loop can also be written directly by `+` on the logical vector as `TRUE` -> 1 and `FALSE` -> 0

```
for(i in 1:100) n.lower <- n.lower + (test.seq[i] < 10000)
```

-output

```
> n.lower
[1] 50
```